# What is the meaning of KEX DH host key and KEX DH H signature in SSH key exchange

Tags: ssh, diffie-hellman

During the Diffie-Hellman key exchange, the server sends a `Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange Reply (31)` message back to the client. This message contains the `DH server f` but also two other pieces of information `KEX DH host key` and `KEX DH H signature`. Could anyone please explain their meaning and what they are good for ? Thank you.

[image: Wireshark Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

`DH server f` - the exchange value used to calculate a shared secret.

`KEX DH H signature` - the signed exchange hash, which is used to authenticate the key exchange.

`KEX DH host key` - the public key of the server, used to sign the exchange hash

See [RFC 4253, Section 7.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#page-21) for more details.